# Manhwa involving a male lead that fakes his disability

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, reincarnation

From what I remember, the male lead(?) fakes disability due to him being a prince and having another brother basically to protect himself. The disability being that he can't talk or walk and has to use a wheelchair. The female lead reincarnated (I forget if it was a book or a game), but I'm pretty sure she then strikes a deal with the male lead. I think the male lead had white hair, but I could be wrong.

Oh and on his 'disability,' only one person aside from the female lead knows; I think it was his personal butler.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Which of the male lead or the female lead was the main character? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Is there anything sci fi or fantasy about this setting?

Comment: For any potential close-voters reading this, the question indicates that the female lead was reincarnated into a novel or game, which would be enough to qualify this as a fantasy story. If my answer below is correct, then that part of the description was seemingly inaccurate, but the story I've named does involve other fantasy elements, such as magic and monsters.

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[I Wasn't the Cinderella](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/3fxce33/i-wasn-t-the-cinderella)***...?

> How could Terryl’s boyfriend leave her simply because of her low status? After her humiliating breakup, a mysterious man tells Terryl the shocking truth about her identity—she’s the daughter of a powerful duke! With her advanced standing in society and newfound powers, Terryl plans revenge against her pitiful ex-boyfriend and contemplates marrying his brother, Cesio. This way, he’ll never get the title of marquis! But what will Terryl do when she discovers Cesio’s dark secret? Will she get her happily ever after, or is that just a fairytale?

The protagonist, Terryl, was in a relationship with Jemon,  but he broke up with her, explaining that he was arranged to be married to Princess Gretel, and that this was necessary in order to ensure that he, rather than his older, adopted brother, Cesio, succeeded their father, Albert Deibrik, as marquis.

Cesio, who has light blond hair, was the son of a distant relative of Albert, and was adopted by Albert prior to Jemon's birth. As far as most people are aware, Cesio can't speak and is wheelchair-bound, but both of these things are a deception he's maintained since childhood. Moreover, he's secretly a royal with magical powers, although his butler knows the truth, and he reveals it to Terryl as well.

She also learns that Jemon was secretly dating Princess Gretel months before he broke up with her, and proposes an engagement of convenience with Cesio, in order to help him, rather than Jemon, succeed Albert as marquis.

From what I've read so far, though, there's no transmigration or reincarnation in this story. Terryl seems to be native to this world, although there could be a reveal in a later chapter I haven't read yet.

[image]

Comment: Is there anything sci-fi or fantasy about this setting?

Comment: @Valorum - Yes. Terryl and Cesio both have magical powers, and monsters appear in certain chapters as well. I've edited this answer to briefly mention Cesio's powers, which include "manipulative diction" and the ability to heal others.